# How can I combind notiifcations into one as each of them are fired off individually?

Tags: android, notifications

I am assigning the same ID to all my notifications so that when I post a new notification using notificationManager.notify, it updates the existing one. This is all well and good, except that it overrides whatever is already there.

If I have 2 seperate notifications, the second notification will just override/hide the first. I want to combine them.

But there does not seem to be a way to access the previous notifications? How can I get the context text of the previous notification so that I can combine it with the context text of the new combination? (Effectively 'merging' them)

Answer (score 0):

you can store the notification content in your shared preference if you want to store only previous notification or you can use Database if you want to store content of all previous notifications.